# Set primary DNS server in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, dns

I would like to set my DNS server to 8.8.8.8.  I followed online instructions and went to Network Connections->Wired Connection 1->Edit->Ipv4 Settings and put 8.8.8.8 into Additional DNS servers.  This does put 8.8.8.8 as a secondary DNS server. I can check this using `nmcli dev show`.

> How can I make `8.8.8.8` my primary DNS server instead?

Comment: You are probably using DHCP; configure your DHCP server accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Automatic (DHCP) addresses only** instead of *Automatic (DHCP)* in the drop down

[image]

Comment: On a server with command line?